# Background worker doesn't catch errors from ThreadPool

Tags: c#, multithreading, exception, backgroundworker, threadpool

I'm using a BackgroundWorker since I need to give a feedback in my UI. I also need to use ThreadPool in my class for it to run asynchronously but it seems that my background worker cannot catch the exception it throws.

*It's intended to give a feedback on what task it's doing.*

I made a simple application which reproduces the problem :

```
    // MAIN UI CLASS

    BackgroundWorker _bgWorker = new BackgroundWorker();

    void _bgWorker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {

        if (e.Error != null)
        {
            // Returns custom error
            MessageBox.Show(e.Error.Message);
        }
    }

    void _bgWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
         try {
            // Initialize test error class
            var testClass = new TestClass();
         }
         catch (Exception ex)
         {
             MessageBox.Show("im from trycatch");
         }


    }
    private void Window_ContentRendered(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _bgWorker.DoWork += _bgWorker_DoWork;
        _bgWorker.RunWorkerCompleted += _bgWorker_RunWorkerCompleted;
    }

    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    // TEST ERROR CLASS
    public TestClass()
    {
        throw new Exception("im a custom error");
    }
```

This works all right. With the try-catch, it catches the error as handled by the try-catch. Whereas, without the try-catch, it handles it in RunWorkerCompleted.

However, I really need to do these methods **asynchronously** (which is why I use ThreadPool) but the **debugger always points at the exception**. *(it only crashes the program when I try it without the debugger)*

```
    // TEST ERROR CLASS
    public TestClass()
    {
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(delegate
        {
             throw new Exception("im a custom error");
        }
    }
```

I tried to rethrow the error using a try-catch statement (hoping it would pass the exception to the BackgroundWorker) but it didn't work.

Hope you can help me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why would a completely separate thread (be able to) pass an exception to the Bgw?

Comment: Just use (another) Bgw or look at the Task and Parallel classes. Bare (pool-)threads don't do exception forwarding.

Comment: A few thoughts ... what version of .NET are you using? If you are using .NET 4 or sooner there are definitely better ways to do this.

Rethink why you would have a background worker's "DoWork" method put something on the ThreadPool. You say you need to use the threadpool for async work, but this is not true, the BackgroundWorker does this for you but calling your 'DoWork' method on a ThreadPool thread... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h01xszh2(v=vs.110).aspx. you need only call RunWorkerAsync which you do not show in your code. This is the point of using BackgroundWorker.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to put code on the ThreadPool from the DoWork method. The BackgroundWorker will raise your `_bgWorker_DoWork` method on a ThreadPool thread automatically when you call `RunWorkerAsync()`.

If you are trying to start SEVERAL MORE ThreadPool tasks from your background worker, then I suppose that could be a consideration, but in that case I would suggest using the TPL in .NET4 if at all possible...

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

If you can not use TPL, then you must wrap your ThreadPool code in a TryCatch and put the Exception some place that can be accessed outside of that method.

For example add a `internal static List<Exception> backgroundExceptions;` member to your UI class, the background worker add's any caught exceptions to this list, and then you must investigate this list after your background work has completed to see if there were any Exceptions present.

This is essentially what the TPL is doing for you ... giving you a place to 'observe' exceptions that happened on the background thread, but it is still your responsibility to look for those Exceptions, either in the `Task.Exception` property, or by calling a method that will re-throw the Exception for you.